# Polygon (formerly Matic) blockchain tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Matic was renamed to Polygon in 2021. This is a source of real confusion, IMO, but we have nothing to do with it. The problem:

- We have the [matic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matic) tag with 30 questions. It is used properly and relates to the chain or MATIC token, but it reflects the outdated brand. However, I don't consider it a real issue, because [`matic.js`](https://github.com/maticnetwork/matic.js/) is not renamed and there aren't any plans to do so.
- We have the [polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon) tag with 4272 questions. Tag wiki:

> For issues relating to the creation, manipulation and rendering of polygons in graphical user interfaces.

So this tag is completely unrelated to the Matic network. However, quick research reveals Matic-related questions (just for two token kinds: [ERC20](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpolygon%5D+erc20) and [ERC721](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpolygon%5D+erc721) - we have 20 and 25 questions, respectively, and almost all of them are not tagged [matic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matic)).

It is clear that [polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon) requires disambiguation. How should it happen in exactly this case, when a proper tag exists? Some questions can be clearly identified (by a tag combination and common keywords), but I'm not sure that checking 4k questions manually is worth it.

Also, is it appropriate to keep the [matic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matic) tag, if it refers to the rebranded organization? Is it worth having at all? Should it be replaced with a new [maticjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maticjs) tag (it does not exist now, but it can be created)?

Comment: These situations always happen when a company thinks it's a smart move to name themselves after a very common term thats completly unrelated to their business area.

Comment: Yeah, and now it is much harder to search for any docs/info, because googling "matic" was great - name is unique and doesn't overlap with other meanings - and googling "polygon" requires careful selection of additional keywords.

Comment: While you brought up a valid issue, I am unconvinced that the [tag:polygon] tag itself requires disambiguation. It's not a fault of a well-known term that a company thought it'll be great for SEO. That still leaves us with what to docwith matic, though.

Comment: I think Matic/Polygon questions are better suited for Ethereum SE, since it is a sidechain. Much more active there too: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygon

Comment: @qwr That doesn't make it off-topic for SO though.

Comment: @SuperStormer I would be very wary of anyone asking about blockchain and claiming that it's programming.

Comment: @Braiam Looking at pretty much any question in the [matic] tag would make it clear that blockchain and programming are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just an attempt at a solution.

Maybe we can create a tag [matic.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matic.js) and re-tag the necessary questions. Then create another tag [polygon-blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon-blockchain), and make [matic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matic) a synonym of it. We can mention in the tag excerpt that matic is regarding the blockchain technology, and questions regarding `matic.js` should use the other tag. In the [polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon) tag, we can mention that questions about Polygon (the blockchain technology) should be tagged using [polygon-blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon-blockchain).

Comment: [tag:polygon-blockchain] as a synonym to [tag:matic] is a great solution, thanks! However, IMO mentioning blockchain in [tag:polygon] wiki is an overkill, since "polygon-blockchain" will pop up near "polygon" when adding a tag and [tag:polygon] has a perfectly understandable description. And enumerating all options "this tag is not for X, Y and Z" in all tags that can be misused looks a bit weird for me (esp. given that polygon blockchain is not very popular as a question topic)

Comment: This will leave polygon as a tag and people will still use it. Just get rid of it to avoid that issue.

Comment: @Braiam The purpose of this question is to set [tag:polygon-blockchain] apart from [tag:polygon]. Questions about the blockchain which are tagged with [tag:polygon] should be re-tagged with [tag:polygon-blockchain]. Regarding the future of the [tag:polygon] itself, that should be a separate question in meta, in my opinion.

Comment: @WrichikBasu if we are going to touch a tag, we should solve all problems with said tags, not just the ones that we deem "worthy".

Answer (score -6):

The problem here is that polygon as a tag exist at all. That is not a programming concept, it's a geometry one, so any solution that does not remove polygon, will still have the same issues that you are seeing today. To actually solve the problem:

- remove polygon of the system,
- create a tag warning speaking of the potential polygon interpretations so it's not created again
- create a tag for both matic.js library and another for the polygon protocol

As bonus points, look very closely to those polygon questions and close those that are off topic, which some are, others are simply too broad or lacking information.

Comment: Polygons are the basis of most 3D and even many 2D computer graphics. That would – in the context of programming – make them programming concepts just as numbers, sequences, graphs, ..., wouldn't it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so would coffee makers, or boats, or planes. The fact that it exist on "programming" doesn't make it a programming concept. There's an easy way to know if it warrants a tag: can I ask questions about polygons, without any relationship to any other tag (see Help Center when to create a tag "you should only create new tags when [...] your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site"). This tag couldn't muster that first hurdle.